# Open mapping theorem and regular function

Tags: real-analysis

(1)Let's start from definition of regular function - $f: \mathbb{R^n}\ni U \rightarrow \mathbb{R^m} $, where $U$ is an open subset in $\mathbb{R^n}, n \geq m$ and $f$ is function of class $C^1$; we call $f$ a regular function if $\forall a \in U \: rank f'(a)=m$, where $f'(a)$ is a linear mapping.

(2)Definition of open mapping: $f: \mathbb{R^n}\ni U \rightarrow \mathbb{R^m} $ is an open mapping if $\forall W \subset U$ open in $\mathbb{R^n}$ $f(W)$ is open in $\mathbb{R^m}$

**THEOREM**: if $f: \mathbb{R^n}\ni U \rightarrow \mathbb{R^m} $, where $U$ is an open subset in $\mathbb{R^n}, n \geq m$ is a regular function(1) then this is an open mapping(2).

**QUESTION** :why is it enough to prove that $\forall a \in U \: f(a) \in int(f(U))$ to prove this theoreom?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: i have full proof but i do not understand main idea which i have written in my question. Why is that so?

Comment: why it implies that image of every open subset is open subset ?